# Simple calculator project

Tags: javascript, html, css

my name is Daniel Asa. I started a project for practice to make the following codes
HTML

```js
function display(val) {
document.getElementById("id").value += val;
}
function solve() {
let x = document.getElementById("id").value;

    let y = eval(x);
    
    document.getElementById("id").value = y;

}

function clr(){
document.getElementById("id").value = " ";
}
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  }

body {
width: 100vw;
height: 100vh;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
background-color: #f1f1f1f1;
font-family: sans-serif;
}

.calculator {
width: 300px;
padding-bottom: 15px;
border-radius: 7px;
background-color: black;
box-shadow: 5px 8px 8px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.61);
}

.display {
width: 100%;
height: 80px;
border: none;
box-sizing: border-box;
padding: 10px;
font-size: xx-large;
background-color: #cccecc;
color: black;
text-align: right;
border-top-left-radius: 7px;
border-top-right-radius: 7px;
}

button {
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
border-radius: 50%;
border: none;
outline: none;
font-size: x-large;
background-color: white;
color: black;
margin: 10px;
}

button:hover{
cursor: pointer;
}

.row {
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
}

.operators {
background-color: #ff9500;
font-weight: bold;
color: black;
}

.equals {
background-color: rgb(85, 84, 84);
font-weight: bold;
color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="calculator">
    <input type="text" class="display" id="id">
        <div class="keys">
            <div class="row">
                <button value="7" onclick="('7')">7</button>
                <button value="8" onclick="('8')">8</button>
                <button value="9" onclick="('9')">9</button>
                <button value="+" class="operators" onclick="('+')">+</button>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <button value="4" onclick="('4')">4</button>
                <button value="5" onclick="('5')">5</button>
                <button value="6" onclick="('6')">6</button>
                <button value="-" class="operators" onclick="('-')">-</button>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <button value="1" onclick="('1')">1</button>
                <button value="2" onclick="('2')">2</button>
                <button value="3" onclick="('3')">3</button>
                <button value="*" class="operators"onclick="('*')">*</button>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <button value="C" class="operators" onclick="clr()">C</button>
                <button value="0" onclick="('0')">0</button>
                <button value="/" class="operators" onclick="('/')">/</button>
                <button value="=" class="equals" onclick="solve()">=</button>
            </div>
    </div>
```

There is no problem so far, but I don't know why in the output of the project, when I click on the values I put, it is like a button, I click on the input I put, it is not displayed?

Does anyone know the problem because I followed the right path as far as I know?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if i do understand you correctly. But you miss to call the display function. You should call `display('0')` in your `onClick` handler not simply `('0')`

```js
function display(val) {
document.getElementById("id").value += val;
}
function solve() {
let x = document.getElementById("id").value;

    let y = eval(x);
    
    document.getElementById("id").value = y;

}

function clr(){
document.getElementById("id").value = " ";
}
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  }

body {
width: 100vw;
height: 100vh;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
background-color: #f1f1f1f1;
font-family: sans-serif;
}

.calculator {
width: 300px;
padding-bottom: 15px;
border-radius: 7px;
background-color: black;
box-shadow: 5px 8px 8px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.61);
}

.display {
width: 100%;
height: 80px;
border: none;
box-sizing: border-box;
padding: 10px;
font-size: xx-large;
background-color: #cccecc;
color: black;
text-align: right;
border-top-left-radius: 7px;
border-top-right-radius: 7px;
}

button {
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
border-radius: 50%;
border: none;
outline: none;
font-size: x-large;
background-color: white;
color: black;
margin: 10px;
}

button:hover{
cursor: pointer;
}

.row {
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
}

.operators {
background-color: #ff9500;
font-weight: bold;
color: black;
}

.equals {
background-color: rgb(85, 84, 84);
font-weight: bold;
color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="calculator">
    <input type="text" class="display" id="id">
        <div class="keys">
            <div class="row">
                <button value="7" onclick="display('7')">7</button>
                <button value="8" onclick="display('8')">8</button>
                <button value="9" onclick="display('9')">9</button>
                <button value="+" class="operators" onclick="display('+')">+</button>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <button value="4" onclick="display('4')">4</button>
                <button value="5" onclick="display('5')">5</button>
                <button value="6" onclick="display('6')">6</button>
                <button value="-" class="operators" onclick="display('-')">-</button>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <button value="1" onclick="display('1')">1</button>
                <button value="2" onclick="display('2')">2</button>
                <button value="3" onclick="display('3')">3</button>
                <button value="*" class="operators"onclick="display('*')">*</button>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <button value="C" class="operators" onclick="clr()">C</button>
                <button value="0" onclick="display('0')">0</button>
                <button value="/" class="operators" onclick="display('/')">/</button>
                <button value="=" class="equals" onclick="solve()">=</button>
            </div>
    </div>
```